# (Java) Statistical analysis assignment

Tags: java, arrays, loops, statistics

I'm currently working on a program designed to perform some statistical analysis. Specifically, I want it to store some random integers (say 10, between min and max inclusive) in an array, compute the min, max, mode, and a few other values through separate methods, and give the user a menu with which to either choose a method (and loop back to the menu, if they do so) or exit.

My biggest problems right now are that the main program requires two inputs to carry out any method (doesn't do anything after putting in the first), and also that each method returns 0 or 0.0.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Stats extends Main
{
    int sampleSize;
    double count;
    double ave;
    double sum;
    int min;
    int max;
    int mode;
    int evenCount;
    int oddCount;
    int countMatching;

    //Constructor: use an RNG to generate sampleSize integers between minValue and maxValue. Store the numbers in an array named 'data'.
    public Stats()
    {
        sampleSize = 10;
        data = new int[sampleSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                data[i] = rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min);
            }
        return;
    }
    //Method: return the sample set's max value
    public int getMax()
    {
        max = data[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] > max)
                max = data[i];
        }
        return max;
    }
    //Method: return the min value
    public int getMin()
    {
        min = data[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] < min)
                min = data[i];
        }
        return min;
    }
    //Method: return the average value
    public double getAve()
    {
        count = sampleSize;
        sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + data[i];
        }
        ave = sum / count;
        return ave;
    }
    //Method: return the mode; in case of a tie, choose the smallest value
    public int getMode()
    {
        int popularity1 = 0;
        int popularity2 = 0;
        int array_item;
        for(int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
             array_item = data[i];
             for(int j = 0; j < sampleSize; j++)
             {
                if(array_item == data[j])
                     popularity1++;
             }
                if(popularity1 >= popularity2)
                  {
                  mode = array_item;
                  popularity2 = popularity1;
                  }
        }
        return mode;
    }
    //Method: return the count of even numbers
    public int getEven()
    {
        int evenCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] % 2 == 0)
                evenCount++;
        }
        return evenCount;
    }
    //Method: return the count of odd numbers
    public int getOdd()
    {
        int oddCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] % 2 != 0)
                oddCount++;
        }
        return oddCount;
    }
    //Display all numbers, formatted in columns (hint: pg. 158)
    public void displaySampleSet()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {

        }
    }
    //Return the count of numbers in the sample set that match the input parameter
    public int countMatching(int match)
    {
        int countMatching = 0;
        return match;
    }
    //Create a list of private variable(s) that belong to the Stats class
    private int[] data;

}
```

And here is the main program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int input;
        int stats;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        Stats g = new Stats();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Stats Program!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Main Menu");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Get max value");
        System.out.println("2) Get min value");
        System.out.println("3) Get the mean");
        System.out.println("4) Get the mode");
        System.out.println("5) Get the count of even numbers");
        System.out.println("6) Get the count of odd numbers");
        System.out.println("7) Display the sample set");
        System.out.println("8) Return the count of numbers in the sample set that match the input parameter");
        System.out.println("9) Exit");
        System.out.println();
        stats = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (stats != 9)
        {
            if (stats == 1)
            {
                g.getMax();
                input=keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Max is: " + g.getMax());
            }
            else if (stats == 2)
            {
                g.getMin();
                input=keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Min is: " + g.getMin());
            }
            else if (stats == 3)
            {
                g.getAve();
                input=keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Mean is: " + g.getAve());
            }
            else if (stats == 4)
            {
                g.getMode();
                input=keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Mode is: " +g.getMode());
            }
            else if (stats == 5)
            {
                g.getEven();
            }
            else if (stats == 6)
            {
                g.getOdd();
            }
            else if (stats == 7)
            {
                g.displaySampleSet();
            }
            else if (stats == 8)

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("View other stats?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1) Max 2) Min 3) Mean 4) Mode 5) Count of evens 6) Count of odds 7) Sample set numbers 8) Count of numbers that match input parameter 9) Exit");
        stats = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Stats Program. See you next time!");
    }

}
```

Both programs are incomplete, but I'm still getting values for each method (after two inputs), loops after they execute, and the exit works as intended.

Any tips or parts that are glaringly wrong/missing? I'd really like to understand this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Suraj, as I think you realize, your question is somewhat broad. It's hard to give concrete advice if the program you've posted is incomplete. Do you mean you haven't posted it all, or that you haven't written it all?

Comment: That I haven't finished writing it. It seems almost done, but I wanted to resolve the return and double-input issues before moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `Stats`, the data array is immediately initialised in the constructor using the `max` and `min` fields. But these are zero at this point (because you leave them blank, and Java initialises blank `int` declarations to zero). You then call your random number generator:

```
data[i] = rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min);
```

`min` and `max` are zero, so this evaluates to:

```
data[i] = rand.nextInt(1);
```

and `Random.nextInt()` returns values up to, but not including, the input (see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)).

So your 'random' data will always be zeros; therefore the minimum, maximum and average will also be zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: setting min and max values seems to have worked, and I'm now getting values for methods 1-6. Also found that I had extra nextInt lines that were causing the double-input issue, so that's resolved. Now just need to figure out how to display the set in columns, count the numbers that match the input parameter...and I'll be done.