# How to find the minimum, maximum , and mode in an array using if statements and for loops (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, max, mode, minimum

First question here, so please be easy on me. Currently learning java for fun and I was hoping I can pick your guys' brain on asking for this.

```js
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (score[i] > max) {
                max = score[i];
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (score[i] < min) {
                min = score[i];
            }
        }
```

When I run the code it gives me my maximum of the array, but the bit with the min doesn't give me the miniumum from the set of inputs in the array.

The next issues i have is with the mode, I dont even know where to start, i really dont know anything complex so something simplistic would be great to help me along. Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you initialize `min` to before you run the loop?

Comment: Do you have problem from storing both the min and max in potentially the same area.? There are situations where finding one value cough prevent finding the second.

Comment: for your question about min. how do you initialize min before the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Java) Statistical analysis assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220158/java-statistical-analysis-assignment)

Comment: @MikhailAntonov That is not a good duplicate, because there's no answer that tells how to compute the mode.

Comment: as for the mode. you can try to use map to store the count of every element.

Comment: @ajb there's a method `public int getMode()` in question. I didn't thoroughly check if method itself is correct, but at a first glance it's OK.

Comment: @MikhailAntonov Oh, sorry, I assumed that the duplicate question was a question.  It looks like the answer is in the question, or something.

Comment: Computing the mode isn't an easy problem.  There are a couple solutions already from other posters.  Another is to sort the array; when you step through the sorted array, all the same elements will be all together, so you can keep a counter to see how many of each element there are, and keep track of which count is the largest.  It will take some thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(score[0]>score[1])
{
  max=score[0];
  min=score[1];
}
else{

  min=score[0];
  max=score[1];
}
for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (score[i] > max) {
                max = score[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (score[i] < min) {
                min = score[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum loop seems to be correct as you have it IF you initialized the min variable outside the for loop. Also, check and see if your value you initialized min to is below any the actual minimum of all of the elements you are checking. This would give you an incorrect reading.

As for the mode part you need to find the number that occurs the most often. Think about how you would go about this. One possibility is to scan the array and have a counter for each number and increment its counter each time you find that number in the array. This may not be the best solution as you will need a counter for each different number in your array but it is a simple example to understand and will hopefully point you in the right direction. Try it out and if you need more help or want a better solution I will edit and update.

Comment: A hint at what could be better is having a variable keep track of the highest multiplicity and use 2 for loops to compare each element in the array against all of the others and count the occurrences. If the current multiplicity is greater than the highest then the new highest becomes the current and you keep track of which element had that multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Just like some other answers suggest, I think the problem lies in the correct initalization of the "min". Try initializing with the first value of the array.

```
// example data
int[] score = {3,1,5,7,2}; 

// initialize min with first score value
int min = score[0];

// find minimum (note that one could start with i = 1, assuming score.length is at least 2)
for(int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
   if(min > score[i])
      min = score[i];
}
System.out.println(min); // should print '1'
```

When putting the code in a method like "findMin(int[] arr)" please remember to make sure to handle arrays that are null or have a length of 1!

please provide more information on what you mean with 'mode'

Comment: the mode is the number that occurs most frequently in a given set of numbers  so, in a 4 number set of {1,1,2,5} 1 would be be the mode. For this program i am trying to write, the user says how many numbers they want to input and i need to use for loops to run through the array to find it